# Wordpress Color PIcker - force a color refresh

Tags: javascript, wordpress, colors

I have a javascript code that changes the color value on several fields when one button is pressed.  It works properly but I need to add a piece of code to refresh the color picker for these fields once I have forced the value to change.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('bkgcolor').value='#dd3333'; document.getElementById('txtcolor').value='#000000'; document.getElementById('linkcolor').value='#dd9933';" class="button">Style 1</a>

<input type="text" id="bkgcolor" class="color-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('bkgcolor') ); ?>" data-default-color="#dd3333"/>

<input type="text" id="txtcolor" class="color-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('txtcolor') ); ?>" data-default-color="#dd3333"/>

<input type="text" id="linkcolor" class="color-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('linkcolor') ); ?>" data-default-color="#dd3333"/>
```

So the javascript forces the fields to change but I need to have the colors refresh once the fields are changed to the "Style 1" value.
Then I can have buttons to quickly switch through multiple styles of colors but then they can be customized accordingly.

All I need really is to know what javascript to intiate in order to force these color-picker fields to refresh once the button has been pressed.

Comment: is this part of the customizer api?

Comment: I think so... not sure... command is wpColorPicker
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/